# Twitter Bootstrap makes background image dissappear

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my main css file I have this:

```
background: url(/images/bg_1.jpg) repeat;
```

And it works fine, I have a background image showing. But when I include the `bootstrap.min.css` v3.1.1 file in the html (**above** my css file in the code), the background just goes white.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: what element is it on? can you include more code?

Comment: Yea the background was on html, i switched to body to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the bootstrap.min.css contains a css declaration which has a higher [specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)
on the element(s) in question. Use firebug or the chrome inspector to look at the styles being applied to this element. You'll be able to see which css declration has a higher specificity and which has therefore overridden your main.css declaration.

Comment: Generic answer but it did get me thinking correctly to fix it, thanks. I added the background to body instead of html element.